# How to get last moved card detail in trello api?

Tags: trello

I am working on trello api for quite some time . I cannot find out a way to get last moved card from one list to another list in trello , I am planning to send an email to content inside card by extracting email address from the card i know it is possible to send emails automatically in trello but here scenario is different , help would be appreciated

Comment: is your goal to "get last moved card from one list to another list in trello"?

Comment: my goal is to send email to the  content ie the email address of the last moved card in trello .

Answer (score 0):

> my goal is to send email to the content ie the email address of the last moved card in trello

- A cards email can be found under the key `email`
- By `last moved card` maybe you should take a look at [the webhooks api](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/webhook)? If you need a simple node bot to manage things. have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/karlpokus/trobot)